# How to optimize loops drawing canvas pattern?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I have the following function that draws a canvas pattern. It works so slow when canvas size bigger then 512x512.

```
const defaultConfig: Divot = { step: 8, triangleWidth: 4, radius: 0.6, strokeStyle: '#000' };

export function DivotTemplate(divot: Partial<Divot> = defaultConfig, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement): HTMLCanvasElement {
  const config = { ...defaultConfig, ...divot };
  const { width, height } = canvas;
  const { step, radius, strokeStyle, triangleWidth } = config;
  const TAU = 2 * Math.PI;

  let x = [1, 1, triangleWidth];
  const y = [1, triangleWidth, triangleWidth / 2];

  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (!context) throw Error('Canvas context error');

  context.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;

  /* Рисуем три точки для первого треугольника */

  for (let c = 0; c < height; c++) {
    if (c % 2 === 0) {
      x[0] = triangleWidth + 1;
      x[1] = triangleWidth + 1;
      x[2] = 1;
    } else {
      let s = step / 2;
      x = [1 + s, 1 + s, triangleWidth + 1 + s];
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < width; i = i + step) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x[0], y[0], radius, 0, TAU);
      context.stroke();

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x[1], y[1], radius, 0, TAU);
      context.stroke();

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x[2], y[2], radius, 0, TAU);
      context.stroke();

      /* Соединяем две точки из трех */

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x[2], y[2]);
      context.lineTo(x[0], y[0]);
      context.stroke();

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x[2], y[2]);
      context.lineTo(x[1], y[1]);
      context.stroke();

      x[0] = x[0] + step;
      x[1] = x[1] + step;
      x[2] = x[2] + step;
    }

    x = [1, 1, triangleWidth + 1];

    y[0] = y[0] + step;
    y[1] = y[1] + step;
    y[2] = y[2] + step;
  }

  context.stroke();

  return canvas;
}
```

As result I get a canvas pattern like:

[image]

I what can I optimize in this code according canvas and loops?

Comment: Would be great if you could turn this in to a working Js snippet

Comment: I published full code there to test it:

https://jsfiddle.net/nbut7jhr/5/

Comment: Also I have added a time start, time end to measure the time execution. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nbut7jhr/6/
It takes 150 ms

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's in TS, so it won't work for a stack snippet.

Comment: I rewrite it in JS in jsfiddle, checkit out

Comment: Prefer [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for code so there's no dependency on an external site.

Comment: You could draw a small version, and then copy and paste this multiple times to make a bigger version. See; [Using images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images).

Answer (score 1):

### Optimizing rendering performance

- Avoid unnecessary state changes.

  `beginPath` then `stroke` or `fill` requires a GPU state change (move data from CPU controlled RAM to GPU controlled RAM). Reducing the number of times you call begin path will increase the performance of your rendering code.
- Don't `throw` in performance code. Code that can throw can flag the function as `Do Not Optimize` meaning it will be ignored by the built in optimizer.
- Avoid array indexing in performance code. Accessing an array element is slower than accessing a variable directly.
- Avoid repeating calculations inside a loop that can be done once outside the loop.

### Basic rewrite.

The rewrite replaces the many `beginPath` / draw calls with one `beginPath` and stroke outside the loops (because all the rendering is the same style). This will result in a significant performance increase.

To avoid the connecting strokes between arcs move to the beginning of the arc using `moveTo(x + radius, y)`

I have changed the signature of the function `DivotTemplate` so that the default parameters is at the end.

```js
const defaultConfig  = { step: 8, triangleWidth: 4, radius: 0.6, strokeStyle: '#000' };
const now = performance.now();
bivotTemplate(canvas);
console.log("1024 by 1024 canvas in " + performance.now().toFixed(2) + "ms");
function bivotTemplate(canvas, divot  = defaultConfig) {
    const config = {...defaultConfig, ...divot };
    const { width, height } = canvas;
    const { step, radius, strokeStyle, triangleWidth } = config;
    const TAU = 2 * Math.PI;
    const halfStep = step / 2;
    var c, i, x0 = 1, x1 = 1, x2 = triangleWidth;
    var y0 = 1, y1 = triangleWidth, y2 = triangleWidth / 2;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;

    ctx.beginPath();
    for (c = 0; c < height; c++) {
        if (c % 2 === 0) {
            x0 = triangleWidth + 1;
            x1 = triangleWidth + 1;
            x2 = 1;
        } else {
            x0 = 1 + halfStep;
            x1 = 1 + halfStep;
            x2 = triangleWidth + 1 + halfStep;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < width; i = i + step) {
            ctx.moveTo(x0 + radius, y0);
            ctx.arc(x0, y0, radius, 0, TAU);

            ctx.moveTo(x1 + radius, y1);
            ctx.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, TAU);

            ctx.moveTo(x1 + radius, y1);
            ctx.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, TAU);

            ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
            ctx.lineTo(x0, y0);

            ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
            ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);

            x0 += step;
            x1 += step;
            x2 += step;
        }
        y0 += step;
        y1 += step;
        y2 += step;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    return canvas;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = "1024" height = "1024"></canvas>
```

### Real-time

The above code will be much quicker then your original,. However it is still rather slow.

As the rendering is a repeated tile pattern you can increase the performance by 2 (maybe 3) orders of magnitude (real-time) using the 2D pattern.

Render the pattern to a canvas (not on the page) the size of one pattern. The use [`ctx.createPattern(canvas, repeat)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern) to create a repeating pattern.

Draw the pattern over the whole canvas using `fillRect`. This will be almost as fast as drawing the pattern on a 8 by 8 canvas (in this case)